# How to use makefiles when compiling with emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, makefile

-

I am trying to compile Fabrice Bellard's [BPG image project](https://bellard.org/bpg/) with emscripten to convert it to wasm.

Mr. Bellard already has a per-compiled version setup to render 3 javascript files. He is using a Makefile to control the build settings.

I'm very new to emscripten (and compiling c in general), so forgive me if this is a noob oversight, but I tried to run the commands given on the [emscripten website](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html) for make files however I get the errors listed below:

**command**: emconfigure configure

**Error**: root:Exception thrown when invoking Popen in configure with args:"configure"

**command**: emmake make

**Error**: make is not recognized as an internal or external command

I don't understand what the first error means at all, and I couldn't find much googling. However the second error I understand what it means but I don't understand why I'm getting it. Isn't make built into emscripten?

Thank you for any help toward this!

Comment: No, you need to install make. Google how to do so. The first step i belive is not required. Get the portable sdk, run emsdk and follow its step to first fetch and then download the latest pre-built binaries(of the Sdk and not individual components)

Comment: @Tarun Gehlaut yes you are correct, after several days of fighting with it I was able to get it to build successfully! I did it in a linux environment and after installing make and skipping the first command (as you suggested) everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Great. Keep going.